# How to accept command-line arguments in the format "-o=1" instead of "-o 1"

Tags: c, linux, command-line

So I have an assignment to write a C program that can take in command line arguments. There are some options that are standard, single-character flags (like -a or -d), but there are also ones that take a parameter. Normally, this would be expressed as -[option] [parameter], but the assignment wants us to pass it in as -[option]=[parameter]. So a valid command would be, say, "./program -a -o=1 [arguments]".

This is a pretty weird and specific implementation that's obviously just meant for this assignment. As such, I can't find much help on how to do this. getopt() handles options with parameters, but not in this strange format. I was thinking I could use getopt_long(), and set "o=" as an option, but would it still recognize "1" as the parameter? There's no space in between the "=" and the "parameter", so how would it know to separate them? Do I have to give up on using library functions like getopt() and instead manually write a function to parse the options myself? Is there some way I could just have getopt() ignore the "=" and treat it as a space?

Any help would be appreciated, even if it's just "yeah, there's no way to do that, you're gonna have to write the function yourself." I can manage that fine, but I'd prefer to figure out if there's a way to do it using preexisting library functions before diving into that.

Comment: For POSIX `getopt` with an optstring of `"d:"` the required argument is allowed to be concatenated to the option character, so that the two command line parameters `-d` `arg` could be combined into a single command line parameter `-darg`. So for the command line parameter `-d=arg`, `optarg` would point to the `=` in `=arg`. So you could reject anything where `*optarg != '='`. That gets you most of the way. The only niggle is that it would also allow the parameter pair `-d` `=arg`, which ought not be acceptable.

Comment: Glibc also has `getopt_long_only` that allows long options that start with a single `-`. Setting the short options `optstring` parameter to `NULL` would allow only long options. If there is a long option `d` with a required parameter, `--d=arg` and `-d=arg` would be equivalent single parameter forms, and `--d` `arg` and `-d` `arg` would be equivalent paired parameter forms.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thank you so much, I didn't realize -d=arg would separate "d" and "=arg". That makes things much easier.